# Is it possible to send me a Discord private message when an user confirm a form sending in my website?

Tags: reactjs, discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to be able to get Discord private message when an user wants to send me a message through my personal website. There is a form inside my website, how can I do this on the onClick button "Send" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into WebSockets. SocketIO has the most support and documentation however for this simple task you can get away with implementing this using the ws package in nodejs.
Make sure the Discord Bot is the Server & the frontend is the Client.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/